# Image.resizeMode doesn't work as expected in react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I followed the instruction(https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html) on using Image.resizeMode to resize my image to fit the content of the view. Below is my code.

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {View, Image,StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native'
    import TabNavigator from 'react-native-tab-navigator';

    class MainComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <TabNavigator tabBarStyle={style.tab}>
                <TabNavigator.Item

                    title="护士说"
                    renderIcon={()=> <Image source={require('../../icons/main/tab-button_01_pre.png') }
                                        resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.cover}/>}

                    >
                </TabNavigator.Item>


            </TabNavigator>

        )
    }
}

const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const style=StyleSheet.create({
    tab: {
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        height: screenHeight * 0.1
    }
})


export default MainComponent
```

Below is the screenshot of my app. The image at the bottom got clipped. I have tried with the Image.resizeMode to be Image.resizeMode.cover, Image.resizeMode.contain and Image.resizeMode.stretch. All of them doesn't have any different on showing the image. What wrong with my code? How can I set the image size to fit the height of the tab bar?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After using uiautomatorviewer to check the view layout I found that the image height is bigger than the navigation item. So after add below style on the Image it works now.

```
image: {

    height: screenHeight * 0.05
}
```